# difference between ischemia and oxygen-glucose deprived medium

Tags: molecular-biology, physiology

Ischemia is roughly defined as insufficient blood flow to a specific region of the body and in the literature it is generally considered as causing oxygen and glucose deprivation in the tissue and therefore cells. Can we induce ischemia by depriving cells from oxygen and glucose in the medium or does it require more than that and ischemia is more complicated?

edit: i know the definition of ischemia maybe i should have said 'mimick' instead of 'induce'. Anyway, here is the better version of my question:

Ischemia is defined as blood flow shortage in a tissue and it is one of the main causes of non-apoptotic cell death. In an article i was reading, the authors claim that [they induced ischemia in the glucose-serum containing medium](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006291X10018486). Does this mean they deprived the cells from oxygen and thus mimicked ischemia? Is this the way to create ischemia in a cell culture? What other ways can there be? Should not cells also be deprived from glucose?

Answer (score 1):

**Ischemia** leads to tissular hypoxia and glycopenia due to an insufficient blood flow (e.g. due to atherosclerosis or thromboembolic diseases). [Ischemia **always result in hypoxia**](http://cvphysiology.com/CAD/CAD005.htm).

**Hypoxia** can occur **without ischemia** (e.g. due to anemia).

Tissular **glycopenia** can occur **without ischemia** (e.g. due to hypoglicemia).

[Ischemia is a shortage in blood supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischemia). Depriving cells form oxygen and glucose isn't the same as cutting their blood supply.